# How to use StencilJs Components in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, stenciljs

I'm working on a UI Lib using stencilJs and in another project I'm using react-native-web to make easier my web and mobile dev. The custom component that I've created in stencilJS project only works on web, in mobile version it shows this error:

> Invariant Violation: View config not found for name My-rating.

Is there a way that I can use my StencilJS components in React Native?

Comment: Any luck? How'd it go?

Comment: Web components only work in a browser/web view because they are a combination of html, css and js. So you would need to wrap them in a web view or use sth like https://github.com/archriss/react-native-render-html. But I'm not sure what's the point of using RN then vs sth like Cordova or Capacitor. Unless you want to mix it with other RN components.